# Parse json with \uxxx chracters using python

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have JSON data,  which contains a text data field with escape characters such as `\n`, `\u4e0d` etc.

Using Python 2.7, my goal is to write it to CSV "as-is" i.e. `\n` as `\n` and `\u4e0d` as `\u4e0d`. (raw strings)

`str(data["text"]).encode('string_escape')` works as expected for `\n` but not for `\u`, giving the error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u4e0d' in position 32`

If I try `data["text"]).encode('utf-8').encode('string_escape')` it works but mangles the `\u` in input like `\xe4\xb8\x8d`

```
data = json.loads(line)
writer.writerow(data["text"]).encode('utf-8').encode('string_escape'))
```

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Many thanks

Comment: use `base64` encoding and decoding technique. It will solve your problem!

Comment: I'm confused... what does "\n as \n" mean? It can't be a 1 character new line character in a csv, that's illegal. Do you mean a 1 character new line becoming a 2 character _slash n_? Should the single unicode character turn into 6 characters _slash u 4 e 0 d_?

Comment: I mean if the JSON data has "\n" somewhere (not really a new line), I want to output it as "\n" in my CSV and not as a new line.

Comment: Given a 3 character example `sample = u"\n \u4e0d"`, `repr(sample)` is `u'\n \u4e0d'` and the python string quoting could be removed by `repr(sample)[2:-1]`, giving `\n \u4e0d`.

Comment: wow! This did the trick ! After juggling through so many solutions..! Could you explain this a bit so that I can confidently use it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the challenges of programming is how to write non-display characters such as *newline* that perform an action instead of displaying a glyph. Python uses the *backslash* plus additional characters to represent these characters. For strings, the python `repr` function gives you the backslash-escaped representation of a string  as if you were typing it in.

If I type in your example string and print it, ... well I get the new line and the unicode glyph but writing to an ascii csv would result in a unicode decode error.

```
>>> test = u'\n hello \u4e0d'
>>> print test

 hello 不
>>>
```

But if I print the string representation, its what I originally typed in

```
>>> print repr(test)
u'\n hello \u4e0d'
>>>
```

If I don't want the python string part, I can just strip it out

```
>>> print repr(test)[2:-1]
\n hello \u4e0d
>>>
```

Which is better depends on what happens to that string next. If you want to get back to the real string later, stick with the python representation and then `ast.literal_eval` to get it back again.

```
>>> test2 = repr(test)
>>> original = ast.literal_eval(test2)
>>> original == test
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a unicode string. You want to write it into csv file as it is. Since you can't write a unicode string on file you tried to encoded it and it got some unwanted character like '\x'. Try this solution which will convert unicode string to string without adding any unwanted character -

```
import ast
data = u' \n \u4e0d'
str_data = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(data))  
writer.writerow(str_data.encode('string_escape'))
```

Comment: Great! Close to solution. But now I am getting extra '\' in the data eg : "Your don't will \nnot allow you to \u4e0d ind this place." becomes "Your don\'t will \nnot allow you to \\u4e0d ind this place." Any idea how I can remove these ?

Comment: Yes I noticed that, Let's try to remove that

Comment: looks like this is special with '\u', no extra '\' getting added if we have char like - '\n' or '\t'.

Comment: Its also adding slashes to single quotes inside the string. @tdelaney seems to have provided the solution by using repr(data)[2:-1]. This gives us the desired output. Not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique to write data to your file. First encode the data using `base64`, and when you want to write to the file just decode it and write that data.

```
>>> import base64
>>> encoded_data = '\n \u4e0d'
>>> data = base64.b64encode(encoded_data)
>>> data
'CiBcdTRlMGQ='
>>> base64.b64decode(data)
'\n \\u4e0d'
>>>
```

Comment: I don't get how I can use this in my case. I am loading a json and then I want to write it to a file. writer.writerow([                base64.b64decode((base64.b64encode(data["text"])))]) won't make any sense I guess.

Comment: Yes, it is not working? The data inside your `data['text']` is a single `string` right?

Comment: Yes it is. And unfortunately its not working. Its giving the same error as using just data['text'] i.e. : UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u4e0d' in position 32

Comment: data = json.loads(line)
writer.writerow(data["text"]).encode('utf-8', 'ignore').encode('string_escape')) try this?

Comment: Same output as data["text"]).encode('utf-8').encode('string_escape') i.e. it handles the \n but the \u comes as \xe4\xe8 etc :(